# Copying and renaming a file into the proper subdirectories

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, dos

I have a particularly tricky batch scripting request. I have a file/folder structure like this

```
/mapcfgs/
  /folder 1/
     somefile.new
     somefile.old
  /folder 2/
     someotherfile.new
     someotherfile.old
  /folder 3/
     someotherotherfile.new
     someotherotherfile.old
/maps/
  /folder 1/
     somefile.inf
  /folder 2/
     someotherfile.inf
  /folder 3/
     someotherotherfile.inf
```

Now, what I am trying to do is to make a script that would copy /mapcfgs/(name of folder)/*.new to /maps/(name of folder)/*.inf

The problem i've run into is that I don't know how to get *just* the folder name of each file that my for statement finds because I need to use that argument in my copy statement.

My script so far looks something like this.

```
@echo off
echo hello
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=\" %%a in (`dir /a-d /b /s mapcfgs *.new`) do copy "%%~dpna.new" "maps/%%~na.inf"
echo script finished
```

However I need to not just copy every file into /maps/, but into the appropriate folder name under /maps, which corresponds to the name of the folder name that the files are in under mapcfgs. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.  It will only echo the command atm for you to check.

```
@echo off
pushd "mapcfgs"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b') do (
echo copy "%%a\*.new" "..\maps\%%a\*.inf"
)
popd
pause
```

Comment: it outputs something like
`copy "folder 1\*.new" "..\maps\folder 1"`
when I am trying to get it to output something like this
`copy "folder 1\somefile.new" "..\maps\folder 1\somefile.inf"`

Comment: You want the `.new` files to be `.inf` try the modification above.

Comment: I tried your modification and theres something very fuzzy going on. The script keeps complaining about not being able to find the file specified even though the command looks correct on the echo output. I even changed the copy command to copy things using absolute paths.

`echo copy "%~dp0mapcfgs\%%a\*.new" "%~dp0maps\%%a\*.inf` which outputs something like `copy "C:\My\Path\mapcfgs\folder 1\*.new" "C:\My\Path\maps\folder 1\*.inf"` The actual command fails saying cannot find path so something fishy is going on.

Comment: Nevermind. The command wasnt working because the folders that I was trying to copy into didnt exist yet. This won't be a problem when I run it on the 'live' folder. Thanks again.

Comment: xcopy /s can also be used to create folders where they don't exist, I just discovered.